# Jquery inside PHP block

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

The Jquery will not run. After the button is clicked, I'd like it add text, "Hello Everyone" after the Say: between the

tags. The jquery.js file is uploaded to my server and is in the same place as the testpage.php file.

Should my button be inside `<html></html>` or is it something else?

my testpage.php code:

```
<?php 
echo '<button id="some-btn">Test</button>
  <script src="jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <p>Say: </p>
                <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#some-btn").click(fucntion (){
                        $("p").append("Hello Everyone");
                    });
                });
                </script>';
?>
```

Comment: You've got a typo there, `fucntion` instead of `function`, that's the culprit.

Comment: lol! thanks. just wow.  dumb newbie mistake

Comment: Also, you don't need to `echo` this. When there are large strings or much HTML, I personally often find it much better to break out of PHP and output it as HTML instead, `?><html><?php`

Comment: I haven't seen that before.  I'll try it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have mistakes in your code. E.g. `fucntion` is misspelt, should be `function`

```
<?php  
echo '<button id="some-btn">Test</button>
<script src="jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<p>Say: </p>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#some-btn").click(function (){
      $("p").append("Hello Everyone");
    });
});
</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Qirel mentionned, I prefer to break the php. That way you prevent having too large strings in PHP.

**Should my button be inside  or is it something else?**

Your elements should be between your body tags. You can also change your click function to the next one:

```
$(document).on('click', "#some-btn",function (){
  $("p").append("Hello Everyone");
});
```

This way your event will trigger even for the elements that are added to the DOM once it is rendered.